# Qt Drag/Drop behavior for custom item type

Tags: drag-and-drop, qt5, qstandarditem

I have a custom item class derived from QStandardItem being using in a QTableView (the model is just QStandardItemModel). I would like to be able to drag items from this view and drop the text (Qt::DisplayRole) onto a separate QTableWidget.

Using just the default behavior everything looks fine during the drag but it doesn't actually drop anything; the target cell stays blank. Is it possible to get the desired behavior without subclassing QTableWidget?